# Convolution that is equiprobable to a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convolution

I am struggling with finding two distributions a and b on the non
non-negative integers (both not concentrated at 0, this is t trivial)
such that the convolution of a and b is the equiprobable  distribution on the set 0,1,...n-1

n is not a prime number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use generating functions, reducing the task to finding a nontrivial factorization of $$\frac1n(1+s+\cdots+s^{n-1})$$ into two polynomials. For example, $$\frac1{k\ell}(1+s+\cdots+s^{k\ell-1})=\frac1k(1+s^\ell+\cdots+s^{(k-1)\ell})\frac1\ell(1+s+\cdots+s^{\ell-1})$$ hence, if $n=k\ell$, $a$ uniform on $\{0,\ell,\ldots,(k-1)\ell\}$ and $b$ uniform on $\{0,1,\ldots,\ell-1\}$ work.

Comment: In other words, if you write $n$ in base $\ell$ with a zero in the ones digit place, you can generate the ones digit and and the tens digit places independently to get a uniform number in the appropriate range.

Answer (score 1):

This "solution" could be considered as a "comment" on... the excellent "solution" given by @Did as a "comment",

$$\tag{*}\frac1{k\ell}(1+s+\cdots+s^{k\ell-1})=\frac1k(1+s^\ell+\cdots+s^{(k-1)\ell})\frac1\ell(1+s+\cdots+s^{\ell-1})$$

but I am close to believe it helps to understand it:

A) **through an example:**

Consider the uniform distribution $d_1$ on the set $\{0,1\}$ and the uniform distribution $d_2$ on the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$.

Let $X,Y$ be independent Random Variables (R.V.) that follow $d_1,d_2$ resp.

Then R.V. $Z:=X+Y$ follows a uniform distribution on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

(we have thus answered the question because the distribution of the sum of 2 independent R.V. is the convolution of their distributions).

Formal proof: Taking into account that $P(X=a)=\frac12$ (for $ \ b=0,1$) and $P(Y=b)=\frac15$, (for $ \ b=0,2,4,6,8$), the two cases to be considered are:

$P(Z=2k)=P(X=0).P(Y=2k)=\frac12.\frac15=\frac{1}{10}$

$P(Z=2k+1)=P(X=1).P(Y=2k)=\frac12.\frac15=\frac{1}{10}$

b) **by giving it a direct proof:** Using the formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression (the first one with ratio $s^{\ell}$, the second one with ratio $\ell$, (*) is transformed into the evident relationship :

$$\dfrac{1-(s^{\ell})^k}{1-s^{\ell}}\dfrac{1-s^\ell}{1-s}=\dfrac{1-s^{\ell k}}{1-s}$$